# watch ouput of src block execution in real time?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I type, e.g.

```
#+begin_src shell :session *foo*
  echo 1
  sleep 5
  echo 2
  sleep 5
  echo 3
#+end_src
```

, hit `C-c C-c` inside the code block and then `C-x b RET *foo* RET`, I have to wait 5 + 5 seconds, after which I see the buffer pop up and the whole output appear at once.  Is it possible to run this code block and watch the output incrementally accumulate in real time, so that the `*foo*` buffer pops up at once, '2' appears after 5 seconds and '3' after another 5 seconds?

Comment: It's a bit flakey for me, but try adding an `:async` header-arg.